# Geopandas faceting by year

Tags: pandas, geopandas, shapefile

In ggplot it is possible to facet by year.

```
ggplot(usa_elections, aes(fill = winner)) + geom_sf() +
facet_wrap(~year,nrow=4) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c('blue', 'red'))
```

[image: Output is this]

In geopandas, is there a way to face by year?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for example like this. You'll have to adjust it to better fit the shape of USA and add a legend.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

df = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/election2.shp')

years = [c for c in df.columns if c.isnumeric()]

#For each year create a color column
colordict = {'republican':'red', 'democrat':'blue'}
for year in years:
    df['color_{0}'.format(year)] = df[year].map(colordict)


fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=4, sharex=True, sharey=True) #Create the plot figure and axes
fig.set_size_inches(5,15)

rows = np.array([0,1,2,3])
cols = np.array([0,1,2])

for xy, year in zip(np.array(np.meshgrid(rows, cols)).T.reshape(-1,2), years):
    print(xy)
    # xy are the indexes to select each axis
    # [0 0]
    # [0 1]
    # [0 2]
    # [1 0]
    # ...
    x,y = xy
    df.plot(ax=axs[x,y], column=str(year), color=df['color_{0}'.format(year)])
    axs[x,y].title.set_text(year)
    
plt.show()
```

[image]